# XMVector3Project giving offset values when object is moved in world space

Tags: directx-11, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to convert world space coordinates to screen space coordinates for a 2D game so I can work on collisions with the edges of the window.

[image]

The code I am using to convert world space coordinates to screen space is below

```
float centerX = boundingBox.m_center.x;
XMVECTORF32 centerVector = { centerX, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };


Windows::Foundation::Size screenSize = m_deviceResources->GetLogicalSize();
//the matrices are passed in transposed, so reverse it
DirectX::XMMATRIX projection = XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_projectionMatrix));
DirectX::XMMATRIX view = XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x4(&m_viewMatrix));
worldMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(worldMatrix);

XMVECTOR centerProjection = XMVector3Project(centerVector, 0.0f, 0.0f, screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height, 0.0f, 1.0f, projection, view, worldMatrix);

float centerScreenSpace = XMVectorGetX(centerProjection);

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "CENTER SCREEN SPACE X: " << centerScreenSpace << std::endl;
OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
```

I have a window width `1262`. The object is positioned at `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` and the current screen space X coordinate for this position is `631` which is correct. However, the problem occurs when I move the object towards the edges of the screen.

[image]

When I move the object to the left, the current screen space X coordinate for this position is `0.107788` when realistically it should be well above `0` as the center point is still on the screen and nowhere near the edge. The same happens on when moving the object to the right.

The screen size in pixels is correct, but something thinks that the screen has a premature cut-off like in the image below. It seems that the red dotted lines are the *edges* of the window when they're not. I can fix this by adding an additional offset but I don't believe that is the correct way to fix it and would like to know where I'm going wrong.

[image]

Does anyone know why the coordinates are incorrect?

**Edit**

World matrix is calculated for each object (black rectangle) in update using

```
XMMATRIX world = XMMatrixIdentity();
XMMATRIX scaleMatrix = XMMatrixScaling(m_scale.x, m_scale.y, m_scale.z);
XMMATRIX rotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationY(0.0f);
XMMATRIX translationMatrix = XMMatrixTranslation(m_position.x, m_position.y, m_position.z);
world = XMMatrixTranspose(scaleMatrix * rotationMatrix * translationMatrix);

//update the object's world with new data
m_sprite->SetWorld(world);
```

I have a feeling this could be something to do with the projection matrix as I'm currently using perspective projection for 2d rendering. Although I should be using orthographic, surely this isn't a problem?

[image]

Comment: Note that in UWP, ``GetLogicalSize`` is not in pixels. It's in [DIPS](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/DPI.htm) which depending on your DPI could be same as pixels or not. You should look at using the ``GetOutputSize`` method of [DeviceResources](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DeviceResources) for actual pixel locations if you draw in them. If you draw in DIPS, then ignore this comment :)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I noticed there were two but didn't know why so thanks. I think at this point I have tried both of them but everything I seem to try gives the same result. Just tested `GetOutputSize` again and it's the same.

Comment: Where did ``worldMatrix`` come from?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I have added to the OP. This matrix is then passed into the conversion function.

Comment: What is ``m_sprite``?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn A class that I can use to hold the information I need to use a sprite. I have a structure of `Object` -> `Quad` -> `Sprite`, where `Sprite` is inheriting from both. However the world matrix is stored in `Object`. This matrix is then used in the render function when passed into the constant buffer for each individual object

Comment: So there are a lot of ways this could be going wrong, so step back and make sure each step is working before adding another. BTW, you might want to use ``SpriteBatch`` from the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) rather that rolling your own.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Any ideas what could be the cause? `SpriteBatch` would be better yes but I need to do this for learning purposes.

Comment: I'd start with the three matrices. Are you using a ortho or perspective projection? 2D usually uses ortho.